# how to call pm files from index file in perl?

Tags: perl, cgi, indexing

I want to use files that are inside cgi-bin folder in perl, I want to call them from index.cgi
When I do this:
use cgi-bin/file_name it doesn't work, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try "do"

```
# read in config files: system first, then user
for $file ("/share/prog/defaults.rc", "$ENV{HOME}/.someprogrc")
{
   unless ($return = do $file) {
     warn "couldn't parse $file: $@" if $@;
     warn "couldn't do $file: $!"    unless defined $return;
     warn "couldn't run $file"       unless $return;
   }
}
```

This is from perldoc example.

Answer (score 6):

When you ask Perl to use a module, it searches the directories in `@INC`. If a module you want to use is located in some other directory, you can do this:

```
use lib 'some/other/directory';
use TheModule;
```

If you don't want the directory to be added to `@INC`, you can implement `use` directly like this:

```
BEGIN {
    require 'some/other/directory/TheModule.pm';
    TheModule->import('foo', 'bar', ...);
}
```

More details on [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), [`use lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) and [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: I assuemd these were no modules, but scripts since they are under cgi-bin/

I finde it a little dangerous to add cgi-bin/ to @INC, don't you?

Comment: @krico If they are not modules, why are they `pm` files? Regarding the concern about adding `cgi-bin` to `@INC`, please see the edited answer.